# Include safetly - relative and absolute paths

Tags: php, html, path

I wanted to know if it is safe to use includes on pages.

I read using allow_url_include is un-safe, I was using it before with absolute paths, but worked out I could bypass the problem with relative paths, but is this really safe?

Also would something like this really work?

```
 <?php 
   $header= preg_replace('/[^a-zA-Z0-9_]/', '', $_GET['header']);
   include "http://mysite.co.uk/directory/$header.php"; 
  ?>
```

Comment: There's always a better way to do it than this. Even passing a key that identifies the header you want is a better idea.

Comment: @JohnConde Could you show me an example or point me in the right direction?

Comment: I added an answer that illustrates what I am talking about.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's an example that illustrates the concept I made in the comments above.

```
$headers = array('loggedin.php','loggedout.php','someotherheader.php', 'etc.php');
$key     = (int) $_GET['header']; // We know it must be a integer so cast to int
$header  = $headers[$key];
include "http://mysite.co.uk/directory/$header";
```

This can be improved upon by verifying the key exists in the array and if it doesn't defaulting to a default header. You also shouldn't be including files via URL. You should be using the path to the file on disk. It's much faster.

Comment: So this assigns a key to the header itself and then you have to write something to verify it matchs? I like the concept but it's going to take me a while to figure out how to implement it right!

Comment: More or less. You just need to verify that the key exists. For example, if `$_GET['header']` is set to `10` that would cause an error in the code above because there is no eleventh element in the headers array. You just need to check for that, and if the key doesn't exist, set it to `0` or `1` (whichever is more appropriate).

Comment: So you could asign all the values in a config file and simply pull that into the script to use? How about with multiple includes? For instance header, footer and sidebar?

Comment: Yes. For multiple includes you can use an array of arrays with each inner array containing the includes to be used for each key.